# Is there any difference between angular.module and window.angular.module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm code reviewing the following:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    window.angular
          .module('moduleName')
          .directive('DirectiveName', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                templateUrl: '/app/moduleName/list/template.html',
                controller: 'someController',
                controllerAs: 'someCtrl',
            }
        });
}());
```

I've been using

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    //etc
```

rather than starting with `window.angular`.

Since I presume angular is scoped against the window, is there any real, practical difference between these two syntaxes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not at all. in browsers window is the global object,

and as written here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window :

> In web pages, the window object is also a global object. This means that:
>
> - global variables of your script are in fact properties of window:
>
>   ```
>   var global = {data: 0};
>   alert(global === window.global); // displays "true"
>   ```
> - you can access built-in properties of the window object without having to type window. prefix:
>
>   ```
>   setTimeout("alert('Hi!')", 50); // equivalent to using window.setTimeout.
>    alert(window === window.window); // displays "true"
>   ```

Answer (score 4):

Any variable defined globally is attached to the window. So no there is no real practical difference.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know, other than syntactically and explicitly declaring, i don't see any real performance difference.

However if you do `window.angular` rather than `angular` i would pick the earlier one because of the intent. For readability point of view it would be better and much cleaner.